# A fast data structure for lower bound and upper bound queries on integers?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, integer, set

i have to maintain a list of numbers, count up to 100,000...

if the data is (for example)

`1, 4, 9, 12, 20, 35, 52, 77, 91`

and i query for a number, say 27, i want the number just immediately previous to 27, available in the list, so that will be: 20

the data is also going to be modified frequently, like lots of Inserts and erases.

currently i am using `stl::set` coupled with

`set<int>iterator it = lower_bound(values.begin(), values.end(), n);`

so

`*it = 35`
and with `it--`, i get 20... but this is not fast enough, the number to queries are large, up to 500,000.. which include changing of my values or look up value.

please give me some pointers.

Comment: You want a "binary tree" structure.

Comment: @wilhelmtell yeah, on my way to be the man in the hat :)

Comment: Are your queries random or could they be sorted?

Comment: @Gabe- The STL set is typically implemented as a BST.  I doubt that building your own BST would be useful unless you built a special type of tree.

Comment: @JohanLundberg random, cannot be sorted.

Comment: What measurements and results have you done to show that this is the bottleneck?

Comment: @MarkB the other part of the program is reading the input, comparing the query type (char compare 'a', 'b' or 'c'... constant time), setting 0/1's in one of the two arrays (constant time)... so with all these, i conclude that its the predecessor look up which is taking time.. i did tried gprof in linux but couldnt understand much of it :-/ if you feel i can read and learn something, please do point me to it.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I meant something like a B-tree that has a linked list of leaf nodes.

Comment: @Gabe- A B-tree is not a binary tree; it's a multiway tree.  Also, I doubt that a B-tree would be useful here, since those are mostly good for minimizing disk accesses, while now the main interest is getting a lower runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few different ideas come to mind.

For starters, there is a specialized data structure for precisely this problem called an [van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) that stores integers in some fixed range [0, U) and supports successor and predecessor searches in O(log log U) time.  This is exponentially faster than using a standard binary search tree to do the comparisons.  If you know an upper bound on the integers that you're storing, this structure might be able to get you a bit more performance.  There are other related structures like the [y-fast trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie) that can also be used here as well.

Second, if the queries you have are uniformly distributed, you may want to build your own binary search tree that is optimized to minimize the number of nodes looked up overall.  Such a search tree is called an optimal binary search tree, and there are fast algorithms for approximating them in O(n log n) time.  In [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8662556/501557), I detailed one approach for doing this.  This preprocessing might give you much faster lookups, since the tree is specifically built to optimize lookup times.  Alternatively, you could look into [splay trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree), which give comparable performance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: excellent :) exactly vEB trees :) got implementation here http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=van-emde-boas-tree

Answer (score 0):

You can divide all number to (for example) 100 vectors

```
1-> [0..99]
2-> [100..199]
.....
```

this vectors should be sorted.Search on vector with lower_bound/upper_bound function usually faster than in associative containers. But for insertin or deleting you will need to resort one small vector.

UPD
I agree with templatetypedf: van Emde Boas tree could be beter solution.

Comment: Interestingly, if you then break those buckets into sub-buckets and repeat this process with a few minor tweaks, you get the van Emde Boas tree structure. :-)

Comment: Wait... this doesn't work.  What if the successor for an element isn't in the same bucket?

Comment: We always know borders for buckets. To find next element we need check next buckets

Comment: That's true, but what if the next element is very far down?  Suppose that lots of the buckets are empty; in that case, you'd have to inspect a lot of buckets before you found one that wasn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

100,000 is small enough that I would consider just using a bit vector...  100,000 bits is only 12.5K, which should be pretty quick to search and will even fit in L1 cache.

Store the bits backward (i.e. 100000 near the end; 0 near the beginning) so that your scan through memory is linear and you can use [`ffs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ffs.html) (if your platform has it).

Comment: In the worst case this could require linear time for the scan.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Yes, in the worst case it might scan 12.5K, linearly.  Depending on the actual distribution of queries, this could wind up significantly faster than chasing pointers through a complex data structure.